# Is there a way to send an object as well as a separate variable in an ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a post request I am doing like so:

```
var addProject = function (project, id) {
            return $.ajax(projectUrl, {
            type: "POST",
            data: { project: project, id: id }
    });
};
```

This is all fine, and it send up my project object (in JSON) with no problem. What i want to do is this request but also add in a key (that does not belong in the project object) that I can pass to the server controller. Any idea if I can do this, or what is a good way to do this. I really don't want to have to go back and change my object models to account for a key that I will only need every once in awhile.

This is an ASP.NET MVC4 project, and it is going back to a web api controller if that matters.

EDIT: here is my server side stuff

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostNew(Project project, int id)
    {
        //TODO grab the client to add the project to
        Uow.Projects.Add(project);
        Uow.Commit();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, project);
        //response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("ApiControllerAction", new { id = client.ID }));
        return response;
    }
```

Maybe I am not being clear enough. I want to pass in the project object, and then just an int variable. Passing project alone works, but if I try to pass the int it gives me a 400 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var addProject = function (project) {
            return 
              $.ajax(projectUrl, {
                type: "POST",
                data: {data1 : 'Object',data2: 'variable'}
              });
};
```

You have just to send 2 data params., object and var..

Comment: The ajax creates absolutely normal POST.. 
How do you get inputed data when you have normal POST form?

Comment: I updated the question with how I am getting it on the server. When I try to do this is gives me a 400 bad request

Comment: Read up on model binding. The javascript data names should be the same as the action method parameters. Depending on the complexity of your Project object the default model binder may or may not be able to bind the data.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to pass a complex object is to JSON-encode it:

```
var addProject = function (project) {
    return $.ajax(projectUrl, {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(project)
    });   
};
```

To decode this on the server side, you will need a JSON decoder of some kind.  I'm sure C# has some available.